# How to use kubectl patch command to update configmap value

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

My configmap looks like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow_cookie: "false"
  log.cfg: |-
  [log]
  level: info
  [log_file]
```

I need to add value for line '[log_file]' like:

src: $LOG_FILE_LOCATION

so it looks like :

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow_cookie: "false"
  log.cfg: |-
  [log]
  level: info
  [log_file]
  src: $LOG_FILE_LOCATION
```

Where, $LOG_FILE_LOCATION is enviroment variable which i exported in my local m/c using 'export' command.

How can I use 'kubectl patch' command to update CM with this additional parameter or any other way to do so.

I need to use this command in kubernets job which will do this updation.

Any suggestion/recommendation is welcomed.

Thank you in advance !

I have used below command:

kubectl patch cm demo-app-config --type json --patch '[{ "op": "add", "path": "/data/log.cfg/[log_file]", "value": "src: $LOG_FILE_LOCATION" }]'

but getting error as below:

The request is invalid

Comment: Can you edit the file in source control, and `kubectl apply` it?  Or use a tool like Helm to generate the correct ConfigMap content?

Comment: The line '$LOG_FILE_LOCATION' needs to be dynamic per environment. so we cannot hard-code that in the source code. We can add 'src: ' only in the source code. with Helm, we are trying to do that using ArgoCD, but it is not getting updated in the CM.  So I was trying to do it using 'kubectl patch' command.